# Killing previous instances at first time,if running

Tags: shell, awk, process, kill-process

Following is my script 'Infinite.sh' code, I am running this script in background,Before running this script, i want to kill all previous instances.
But this is killing my curent instance also.

```
kill -9 `ps ux|grep Infinite.sh|awk -F\  '{print $2}'`
while true;
do
echo -n "SLEEPING FOR 5 SECOND"
date
sleep 5
done
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just eliminate the current process' PID from the list.  To do this making just the minimal change to your code:

```
kill -9 `ps ux | grep Infinite.sh | awk -F\  -v pid=$$ 'pid != $2 {print $2}'`
```

The option `-v pid=$$` sets the awk variable `pid` to the value of the current process' process ID.  The expression `pid != $2 {print $2}` will print a process ID only if it differs from the current process' process ID.

#### Simpler Code

To simplify the code, we could use `pgrep`:

```
kill -9 $(pgrep Infinite.sh | grep -v $$)
```

#### Which Signal to Send to Terminate a Process

As triplee points out in the comments, **`kill -9` should only be used as a last resort.**  `-9` (SIGKILL) prevents a process from cleaning up after itself, deleting temporary files, etc.  Other signals that one may want to try first include   `-2` (SIGINT), `-6` (SIGABRT), or `-15` (SIGTERM, which is the default). As for which signals to use, [Randal L. Schwartz](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#uuk9letter) recommends:

> Generally, send 15, and wait a second or two, and if that doesn't
> work, send 2, and if that doesn't work, send 1.  If that doesn't,
> REMOVE THE BINARY because the program is badly behaved!

For more details on why `kill -9` should be avoided, see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8916/when-should-i-not-kill-9-a-process).  For more information on the various Unix signals and their meaning, see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal#List_of_signals)

#### Still Simpler Code

As mattalxndr points out, modern Linux systems offer `pkill` which reduces the command needed to:

```
pkill Infinite.sh
```

Unless another signal is specified, `pkill` sends `SIGTERM` (15) which is the preferred signal to send for a first attempt to kill a process.  `pkill` offers a variety of options.  See `man pkill` for details.

Comment: Absolutely [don't use `kill -9`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#kill) unless you know exactly why you need the `-9`.  A regular `kill` should be all it takes in many cases; if not that, then try `-2` instead of `-9`.

Comment: @tripleee Very good point.  I made several updates to this old answer including adding a discussion of signals.

Comment: You could simplify the code even further by using `pkill` instead of `pgrep`.

Comment: @mattalxndr Good suggestion!  I just added `pkill` to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Anything can be dangerous. The better solution is to save your PID to a file everytime you run an instance. If a PID file exists and if the PID in that file is a valid and is an active process, kill that process. Save the PID of the current process after.

```
PID_FILE=/var/run/infinite.pid

# Read saved PID of previous instance.
read PID < "$PID_FILE"

# You may consider other safer signals like TERM, HUP, QUIT, and ABRT.
# Checking may also be optional. You can just send the signal right away.
kill -s 0 "$PID" &>/dev/null && kill -s 9 "$PID" &>/dev/null 

# Optionally wait for process to exit.
sleep 2s

# Optionally check it again.
kill -s 0 "$PID" &>/dev/null && { echo "Unable to kill process $PID."; exit; }

# Save PID.
echo "$$" > "$PID_FILE"
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply check if the pid is the same as the one of the running script.

Something like this could work:

```
#!/bin/bash

pids=($(pgrep "$(basename "$0")"))

for i in "${pids[@]}"
do
    (( $$ != i)) && kill "$i"
done

while :; do sleep 1;done
~
```